# SyntaxError: Unexpected token u at Object.parse (native) NodeJS for JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing

I am in the learning stages of NodeJs and I was trying to get values of parameters from the json passed in the URL. I am using body parser because i saw many stack overflow answers using the same to parse through the data.

***Below is the URL I am passing,***

```
http://localhost:1337/login?json={username:rv,password:password}
```

***I am getting the error mentioned below,***

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
at Object.parse (native)
at C:\Users\summer\Desktop\nodejs\practise3.njs:14:17
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\summer\Desktop\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\Users\summer\Desktop\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\summer\Desktop\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\summer\Desktop\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at C:\Users\summer\Desktop\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:277:22
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\summer\Desktop\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
at next (C:\Users\summer\Desktop\nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
at jsonParser (C:\Users\summer\Desktop\nodejs\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:100:40)
```

***The code is mentioned below,***

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyparser.json());

app.get('/login',function(req,res,next){
    var content = '';
    var data = '';
    data = req.query.json;
    content = JSON.parse(data);        //I am getting the error here
    res.writeHead(200,{"Content-type":"text/plain"});
    res.write(data);
    res.end();
});

http.createServer(app).listen(1337);
console.log("Server Started successfully at Port 1337");
```

Note: After reading this question, if you know other alternatives for collecting values from json data, please do tell.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of this:

```
data = req.query.json;
content = JSON.parse(data);        //I am getting the error here
```

Try for this:

```
data = req.query.json;
var stringify = JSON.stringify(data)
content = JSON.parse(stringify);
```

Answer (score 7):

`JSON.parse` is choking because unlike Javascript, JSON requires all key names to be in quotes [0], so your JSON should be

```
{"username":rv,"password":password}
```

The error "Unexpected token u..." is occurring when the JSON parser encounters the "u" at the beginning of "username", when it expected a quotation mark.

[0] There is a very readable summary of the JSON spec at http://json.org.

Comment: I figured out the whole thing and btw both key and value should be in quotes(" ") for JSON parsing to work.

Answer (score -3):

This happens because the key name must be enclosed within **double quotes**. Here is a workaround to overcome this issue:

```
var jsonObj = eval('(' + YOUR_JSON_STRING + ')');
```

Comment: Just want to point out that this is dangerous if  `YOUR_JSON_STRING` is user input!